# In Backbone.js, what is the opposite of collections.fetch()?

Tags: javascript, http, backbone.js

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch

According to the doc, "fetch" hits a url and GETS data.

How about POST? What if I want to CREATE or UPDATE something? What do I do ?

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save ?!?

Comment: The opposite is of `collections.fetch()` is `()ɥɔʇǝɟ˙suoıʇɔǝןןoɔ`.

Answer (score 0):

The "opposite" is `save`.

> `model.save([attributes], [options])`
>
> Save a model to your database (or alternative persistence layer), by delegating to
>   Backbone.sync. The attributes hash (as in set) should contain the attributes you'd like to
>   change -- keys that aren't mentioned won't be altered. If the model has a validate method,
>   and validation fails, the model will not be saved. If the model isNew, the save will be a
>   "create" (HTTP POST), if the model already exists on the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP PUT).

Comment: That would be the closest "opposite". It works per model. There is no direct "save" for the whole collection at once.

Comment: true, but a simple loop should do.